# How to use Aggregation by range time and terms

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Idea: Search Top events on specific range and order by start_time. Like:

```
    {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 7,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    { "bool": { "must_not": { "term": { "status": "OK" } } } },
                    { "bool": { "must": { "term": { "is_blocked": false } } } }, {
                        "range": {
                            "start_time": {
                                "gte": "2016-01-01",
                                "lte": "2016-03-01"
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "geo_distance": {
                                    "distance": "150km",
                                    "coordinates": "xx.xxx, zz.zz "
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [{ "start_time": "asc" },
        { "attending": "desc" }
    ]
}
```

I quite new on this concept of aggregations so still with basic problems to understand
I wanna 7 results of top events for the next 2 months. So I have two attributes to look. The max of people attending(attendings) is the definition of Top, but also I wanna order this by time(start_time: asc)
What I start to wrote but is wrong:

```
    {
            "aggs": {
                "aggs": {
                    "event_interval": {
                        "date_histogram": {
                            "field": "start_time",
                            "interval": "2M",
                            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                        }
                    },
                    "max_attending": { "max": { "field": "attending" } },
                    "_source": {
                        "include": [
                            "name"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to aggregate the results? Do you want to get the actual documents back for the top 7 events sorted by the number of attendants? If yes, you might need a regular query without any type of aggregation.

Comment: yes, I need the event back, but also sorted by start_time. That why I also looked at top_hits with no success

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to be using an aggregation to get what you are looking for, I think that a simple query can yield the results you would like to see, try this:

```
{
  "size": 7,
  "sort": {
    "attending": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "start_time": {
              "gte": "now-2M",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I'm using the query to search by geo_point, start_time and other conditions

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?